# All combinations of list elements, while each element keeps position

Tags: scala, list, combinations

I am an absolute beginner in Scala and I would like to produce all the possible combinations of the elements of a list, but while each element keeps its position in the list.

For example, if I have the list **List(1, 1)**, I would like to get something like this:

```
List(1,1)

List(1,*)

List(*,1)

List(*,*)
```

where * denotes the elements that don't participate in the current combination.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the definition

```
def f(xs: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = xs match {
  case Nil => List(Nil)
  case h :: t => for (y <- List(h, '*'); ys <- f(t)) yield y :: ys
}
```

This here:

```
f("1123".toList) foreach println
```

gives:

```
List(1, 1, 2, 3)
List(1, 1, 2, *)
List(1, 1, *, 3)
List(1, 1, *, *)
List(1, *, 2, 3)
List(1, *, 2, *)
List(1, *, *, 3)
List(1, *, *, *)
List(*, 1, 2, 3)
List(*, 1, 2, *)
List(*, 1, *, 3)
List(*, 1, *, *)
List(*, *, 2, 3)
List(*, *, 2, *)
List(*, *, *, 3)
List(*, *, *, *)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted ! Thanks a lot !